# EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter instead of HibernateJpaVendorAdapter issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

using an application which consist of JSF, Spring and Hibernate. My example runs normally, then when i changed the class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" to class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter", application didnt run normally. What's the problem? Either of them are JPA spesificition impelementation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.usta.spring" />
 <tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" >
    <!-- p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter"-->
  <!--  <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
       <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>     -->

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter">

    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Spring_PU"/>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/spring"
        p:username="root" p:password="root" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean>

<!--    <bean id="jpaAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        p:database="MYSQL" p:showSql="true" p:generateDdl="true" />    -->

<!--    <bean id="yazikontrolor" class="com.usta.spring.YaziKontolor" scope="request"/>  -->


</beans>
```

Errors :

```
May 27, 2012 7:21:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'yaziServisi': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/marmara.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1073)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/marmara.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:529)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:495)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified
```

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you anything when you don't provide the errors?

Comment: will you tell me anything with providing errors???

Answer (score 66, accepted):

By default, EclipseLink expects run-time **weaving** to be enabled, otherwise you will receive an error in the form 'Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified'. This means that for cases using build-time weaving or no weaving at all, you will need to explicitly indicate this behavior. In order to disable EclipseLink weaving you will need to either configure an application's EntityManagerFactory Spring bean with:

```
<property name="jpaPropertyMap">
  <map>
    <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
  </map>
</property>
```

or add the

```
<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
```

to your application's persistence.xml file.

I recommend to activate the weaving since it's a great improve in performance.

To configure the default run-time weaver expected by EclipseLink, add the following:

```
<property name="loadTimeWeaver">
  <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
</property>
```

to your application's EntityManagerFactory Spring bean.

Then add this option to your JVM :

```
-javaagent:/path-to-your-javaagent/org.springframework.instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
```

In Spring 3.x the javaagent is localized in the org.springframework.instrument jar.

You need the *org.springframework.instrument* library together with *aspectjrt.jar* and *aspectjweaver.jar* libraries.

**Reference**

- [Optimizing JPA Performance](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-performance-optimization&default=false&zid=159&browser=17&mid=0&refresh=0)

Comment: Very Very Very Very Thanks Kaalras, but what's the weaving? what the goal weaving is?

Comment: Weaving is a technique of manipulating the byte-code of compiled Java classes. EclipseLink uses weaving to enhance both JPA entities and Plain Old Java Object (POJO) classes for such things as lazy loading, change tracking, fetch groups, and internal optimizations.

Comment: With weaving true , my application doesnt run, any way to use it with weaving attribute as true?

Comment: @Kaalras Great, it works, but loadTimeWeaver slows my application (the unit test) down, no matter whether weaving is turned on or off.

Comment: is it possible to add Spring instrument as an library rather than javaagent?

Comment: No, since weaving needs something to be loaded _before_ the application (web server) is started. The javaagent is the only way to achieve this.