# Spring Data, EclipseLink, and SimpleLoadTimeWeaver; domain classes loaded by different ClassLoaders

Tags: java, spring

I have a project using Spring Data and EclipseLink. When I try to run, I get this.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [CLASSNAME] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>scrumspurs.domain.User</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.`

When I debug, I can see my domain classes are loaded into the Metamodel. However, they are not `equals` when the Spring Data repositories are being set up. When I investigated I found that the ones that are loaded in the Metamodel are loaded by `org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleInstrumentableClassLoader` and the ones being checked are loaded by `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`.

I'm using a `SimpleLoadTimeWeaver` with EclipseLink just to try to get up and running. Is this supported? Is there something that needs to be done to have this setup work properly?

Comment: could you post a complete stacktrace will all the Caused By's, if it's too big can you post a link to pastebin.com?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem until I used InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. I found answer here:
[loadTimeWeaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769051/eclipselinkjpavendoradapter-instead-of-hibernatejpavendoradapter-issue)